# Toggling between 3 workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I got a MAIN WORKBOOK which creates a new workbook with specific worksheets and headers and it will not save the workbook so it will be a random name like Book1 or Book2. This part is successful. Next thing that it will do is open a file and copy the data of the opened file to the created UNSAVED workbook ("Book1" or whatever is the name)

Problem is I can't switch windows between the source data workbook which is the opened file and the unsaved workbook. I tried windows("workbook name").activate but it only works for the specific name. I need the unsaved workbook to be activated. In short I have 3 opened workbooks.

```
    Sub CopyData()
    Dim Newbook As Window
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant

    'Set source workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Open the target workbook
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All-Files,*.xl**", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open vFile
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A65536").Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate   'Part where it should open the "unsaved file" and copy it
    wb.Worksheets("Prices").Range("A3").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) ' unsaved file

    End Sub
```

Comment: Use a variable e.g. ```Dim newBook1 As Workbook``` and use ```Set``` to store the reference to the new workbook in the variable ```Set newBook1 = Workbooks.Add```. Then use the variable ```newBook1``` whenever you need to work with the new book.

Comment: Note: [macros] tag explicitly states "*Not for MS-OFFICE / VBA / macro languages."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you just need to use the `Workbooks` instead of `Windows`.

```
Workbooks("workbook name").Activate
```

See MSDN for documentation on the [`Workbook` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx).

**EDIT:** Originally misunderstood your question. @Mielk has now answered how you can achieve what you're after. But, for clarity, see the answer below too.

Not sure if you know that the unsaved workbook will consistently be called "Book*", but if it is, you can use this:

```
Sub workbookActivate()
    Dim wb3 As Workbook, wkb As Workbook
    For Each wkb In Workbooks
        If Left(wkb.Name, 4) = "Book" Then
            Set wb3 = wkb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wkb
    wkb.Activate
End Sub
```

Just an alternative.

Comment: He doesn't know what the name of workbook is, it can be "Book1", "Book2" etc.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood. Will edit answer, just for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the reference to the newly opened workbook by assigning the result of the function `Workbooks.Open` to a variable. So instead of those two rows:

```
Workbooks.Open vFile
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
```

you need to put this one:

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
```

Now you have two variables:

- `wb` pointing to your original workbook,
- `wb2` pointing to the newly created workbook.

---

When referencing to ranges you need to put the proper variable at the beginning, i.e.:

```
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A65536").Copy
```

This line `Windows("Book1").Activate` is no needed anymore, since if you refer to workbooks by variables you don't need to activate them to copy & paste data.